# How to go "without navigation bar view controller" to "with navigation bar view controller" in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have project and it has many `view controllers` , e.g. `StartViewController` (**Has Navigation Bar**). Also `processViewController` and `processViewController` has many `views` and `processViewController` **doesn't have Navigation Bar** .

processViewController has `Close button` and action with;

```
@IBAction func goStart(sender: UIButton) {
    let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StartViewController") as! StartViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
}
```

When I push it then;

```
navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColorFromRGBs(0x000000)
navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor();

let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 164, height: 38))
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
let image = UIImage(named: "logo")
imageView.image = image
navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Those lines give error.

How can I fix it ? How can I go from without navigation bar view controller to with navigation bar view controller?

Comment: which line is error

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik    navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColorFromRGBs(0x000000) here bro

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik comming without navigation bar segue to with navigationbar view controller i think gives this

Comment: are you declared the method of `UIColorFromRGBs`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik yeah worked fine !

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i used it many times in my project

Comment: ok what is the error can you show the error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way how you can go from the view controller without navigation bar to view controller with one, is to **present it modally**.

So when you are creating that view controller, that you want to present in it's parent view controller, embed this target controller in navigation controller and then present that navigation controller, that contains your target view controller.

## Swift 3

```
let targetViewController = UIViewController() // this is that controller, that you want to be embedded in navigation controller
let targetNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: targetViewController)
        
self.present(targetNavigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

That because you are trying to getting `navigationController` or `navigationBar` in class or `viewcontroller` which is not embed with navigation controller. So you will get `nil` as `navigationbar` or `navigationController` so that you can't set it's property because it is nil or not exist for current `viewcontroller`.

Manage this things in your `viewcontroller` that have navigation controller `embed`!

Comment: You need to set navigation bar's different properties in `viewController` which is embed with `navigation controller`!! Tell me where are you setting `barTintColor` ? and your question is also not pretty clear that what is exact you want!! give necessary information so that i can help!